# Spring boot serving static resource

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I work on spring boot application. I'm trying to serve static content with spring.
want to serve a resource stored in the /c:/frontend/files/ directory whenever a request comes in for the URL matching the pattern: /file/**:

```
 @Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

    registry
            .addResourceHandler("/file/**")
            .addResourceLocations("file:///C:/frontend/files/" );

}
```

but when i try to access to this resource using this url: http://localhost:9999/file/app.min.js

I have this problem

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Acceptable, status=406).
Could not find acceptable representation
```

Comment: Could you add the curl request + headers for both request and response?

Answer (score 2):

I resolved the problem. it's related to "spring-cloud-config-server". I just delete this config: org.springframework.cloud spring-cloud-config-server

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your project's folder structure is wrong.

Code should go under `src/main/java` and resources (like your javascript) should go under `src/main/resources`. You have a few different options where you can actually serve the files from. [This post](http://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot)   on the spring.io blog has the following to say:

> Spring Boot will automatically add static web resources located within any of the following directories:

- `/META-INF/resources/`
- `/resources/`
- `/static/`
- `/public/`

Another option you also have is using [webjars](https://spring.io/blog/2014/01/03/utilizing-webjars-in-spring-boot).

Personally, I've found it easiest to put those kind of files under `src/main/resources/public`. It always works without any issues for me. The interesting thing is you can put a folder named `/public` anywhere in your project and spring-boot will serve files out of it. You have to be really careful that it's under `src/main/resources/public` though if you're using a build tool like maven, as when you come to build your .jar the files won't be in the right place otherwise.

Comment: Yes, folders with static content should be under class path or directory deploying web app. So one way is to put the static folder under `src/main/resource`, then Maven will help build it into class path.